# Inserting variables with SQL in Java

Tags: java, sql, derby

I'm writing a webpage that takes input from a form, sends it through cgi to a java file, inserts the input into a database through sql and then prints out the database. I'm having trouble inserting into the database using variables though, and I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me out.

```
String a1Insert = (String)form.get("a1");
 String a2Insert = (String)form.get("a2");
```

This is where I get my variables form the form (just believe that it works, there's a bunch more back end but I've used this before and I know it's getting the variables correctly).

```
 String dbURL = "jdbc:derby://blah.blahblah.ca:CSE2014;user=blah;password=blarg";
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.executeUpdate("set schema course");
 stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO MEMBER VALUES (a1Insert, a2Insert)"); 
 stmt.close();
```

This is where I try to insert into the databse. It give me the error:

```
Column 'A1INSERT' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE statement then 'A1INSERT' is not a column in the target table.
```

If anyone has any ideas that would be lovely ^.^ Thanks

Comment: There is good information for you at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html and at  http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/

Comment: If you get the syntax right -- stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO MEMBER VALUES ('" + a1Insert + "', '" + a2Insert + "')");  -- then it will technically work, but would leave you open to SQL injection attacks if somebody can manipulate a1Insert/s2Insert and set them to malicious values. So instead, you should follow the method wit PreparedStatement that Nathan mentions.

Comment: @NeilCoffey except that the correct SQL specifies the column names in the insert statement. So would need to be ... into member (colname1, colname2) values (value1, value2)

Comment: @jwenting In principle you can leave out the column names if the values match up.

Comment: @NeilCoffey and there can be no confusion as to the column order you implied... I've had databases give errors leaving them out on inserting all columns with ambiguous column order (e.g. a table with 2 columns, both varchar).

Comment: @jwenting To the DB, there's no confusion. To the *human* reader, there's obviously room for confusion and leaving out the column names in the code is clearly asking for trouble when it comes to metadata changes where you're liable to forget to update the code. So in real life, I would recommend including the column names. But for the purpose of the post here, I was just pointing out the correction to what was actually causing the issue in this case.

Comment: @NeilCoffey it is ambiguous, and you should always thrive to remove ambiguity. To the database engine, who knows? I've had databases refuse to accept inserts without explicitly named columns even when inserting all columns...

Comment: @jwenting The column order should simply be that specified in the table metadata -- as I say, in principle, it really shouldn't be a big mystery which order it's expecting the columns in! But I would agree it's largely by the by-- the best practice is simply to specify the column names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`java.sql.Statement` doesn't support parameters, switching to [`java.sql.PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) will allow you to set parameters. Replace the parameter names in your SQL with `?`, and call the setter methods on the prepared statement to assign a value to each parameter. This will look something like

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO MEMBER VALUES (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, "a1");
stmt.setString(2, "a2");
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

That will execute the SQL

```
INSERT INTO MEMBER VALUES ('a1', 'a2')
```

Notice the parameter indexes start from 1, not 0. Also notice I didn't have to put quotes on the strings, the PreparedStatement did it for me.

Alternatively you could keep using Statement and create your SQL string in Java code, but that introduces the possibility of SQL injection attacks. Using PreparedStatement to set parameters avoids that issue by taking care of handling quotes for you; if it finds a quote in the parameter value it will escape it, so that it will not affect the SQL statement it is included in.

Oracle has a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) here.